# Lookahead and lookbehind with regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a regex pattern and I'm a beginner.

The string looks like this

`INITIAL TEXT\KEYWORD1\TEXT1\KEYWORD2\TEXT2\KEYWORD3\TEXT3`

The string starts with initial text but the **keywords with their texts could be in any order or may not be present**.
The initial text could contain any character including backslashes.

**I want to capture the initial text** so I tried something like this

`(?<=(.*)(?=\KEYWORD1\|\KEYWORD2\|KEYWORD3).*)`

I am able to capture it on regex101 in group1 but my java code doesn't recognize the group 1.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: To capture the initial text, just use `^[^\\]+`, see the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/G9LXNZ/1).  Note that in Java regex, you would have to use 4 backslashes, i.e. use `^[^\\\\]+`

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention but initial text could also contain backslashes or any character

Comment: Would the second path element _always_ have exactly the text `KEYWORD1`?  Or, could _any_ of the three keywords happen to appear in the second position?

Comment: Any of the three keywords could appear in the second position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string *starts* with the text you want to capture, then you can use a start-of-string anchor followed by a lazy match on any character, terminating with a forward lookahead to one of the keywords (or end-of-string, to allow for the case with no keywords):

```
^.*?(?=\\(?:KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2|KEYWORD3)\\|$)
```

This will match only the `INITIAL TEXT`

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5C4iNR/3)

Note that in Java you will need to double the backslash characters in the regex string. [Demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/jx4NWq)

Comment: This works but not if there is nothing after initial text like end of string

Comment: Got it        ```^.*?(?=\\(?:KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2|KEYWORD3)\\|$)```    Thanks!

Comment: @adamn2 was just updating the answer to exactly that :)